# How to pass data between fragments when using bottomNavView

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation

I have an app with one activity and two fragments, And I navigate using jetpack navigation.

In my "Main" fragment, I've a button that trigger function inside the viewModel:

```
   edit_text_button.setOnClickListener {
            homeViewModel.onButtonClicked()
    }
```

**onButtonClicked** inside **viewModel**, basically shuffle the list and trigger observer in main fragment.

```
   fun onButtonClicked() {
        initList = (1..9).shuffled()
        _list.value = initList
    }
```

My question is: How can I pass every time the updated list to the second fragment in my bottom nav bar?

For example if my list is `[4,5,6]`, I want that the list inside the other fragment will be  `[4,5,6]` etc

**UPDATE - Layout Code**

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

**navigation**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.sampleproject.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.sampleproject.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

</navigation>
```

**menu items(bottom nav view)**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard))
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

Comment: You are using navigation component. Pass data using safe args. Checkout this link - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#safe_args

Comment: Ya I know how to use sagrArgs, But the "problem" with menu items that i don't call direct action in order to navigate to them

Comment: Please add code to get things more clear.

Comment: I updated layouts code, If you need more let me know

Comment: You can use `navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` and use `navController` to navigate to destination with arguments.

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- **activity scope** (`val viewModel: YourViewModel by activityViewModels()`)

  or
- **navigation graph scope** (`val viewModel: YourViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.desired_graph)`)

to access desired data from different fragments in that scope.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I'd recommend preferring the nav-graph scope in pretty much all cases (except if something truly is application-global). Bonus points if the ViewModel receives a SavedStateHandle (which is the default if the ViewModel only gets a SavedStateHandle as constructor argument).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to attach `DestinationChangeListener` to your `NavController` then whenever destination changes with respect to the navController the listener will get called and you can compare destination id and pass arguments to destination.

like below

```
private val onDestinationChangeListener =
        NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
           if(destination.id == <id you want to add args>){
                destination.addArgument("Mata", NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(arrayOf(1,2,3,4)).build())
            }
        }

navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(onDestinationChangeListener)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this code

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener{_,_,arguments ->
                arguments?.putParcelable(DEVICE_PARAMS,deviceArgument)
            }
```