# Is it a good practice to load large data into viewModel or load smaller data as needed

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

Supposed we have 3 fragments and only 2 are using a spinner of person (selection purpose).

My question is: is it a good practice to load all person list in `mainViewModel` and share it between other fragments, or just load data when needed. (Load list of person in the first fragment and load it again in the second fragment).

Comment: There is no disadvantage of using `repository` so always its a better practice to use it whenever you are using `viewModel`

Comment: Actually my question, there's a problem (performance purpose) to load all data into ViewModel, I mean large data, that could be used in other fragments, or that will lead to a leak of performance

Comment: You should keep the fragments independent, but you can use a cache for better performance

Comment: you can see my answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575958/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments-when-using-bottomnavview/61576361?noredirect=1#comment108922415_61576361).

Comment: If both of fragments are on the same activity then you should share your data via livedata from shared view model. Make sure that it's not consuming lot of memory as your viewmodel is shared now via activity, so it would stay alive as long as activity is.